# kdb - impose timeout on remote query with already opened handle

Tags: kdb

I have a process with a several open handles to gateways, rdbs, hdbs etc.

These handles are maintained in a simple in-memory table.

I'd like to find a way to query a remote function but imposing a timeout on my side? is that possible?

e.g

```
h: .conn.getHandle[`someAlias]; / this is literally returning the handle number
h({
  system"sleep 10" 
 }; ())
```

can I somehow impose a timeout such that after 5 seconds the above call throws an error or have some sort of retry logic?

Answer (score 1):

add

```
\T 5
```

before the query, or when starting the q process use:

```
q -T 5
```

Comment: I dont have control of the underlying rdbs/hdbs/gateways, so adding a \T or system "T" is not an option

Answer (score 0):

You could use the timeout functionality via the \T system command if you want the timeout applied to all remote calls

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#t-timeout

You would use this option on your backend process (RDB/HDB), then any queries sent to these processes will be killed after the timeout specified

Comment: this is the thing I dont want to impose this on any rdb/hdb. I want to impose it on my process.

Comment: Not sure if there is an easy way to do that. Maybe if you have another q process that can send a system kill command (I'll call it 'kill process') to the HDB based on a timeout. Your q process could send a message to the to kill process, letting it know the timeout and the HDB details, then send your query to the HDB. When the query completes you would let the kill process know. The kill process would monitor the time, and if it is longer than the received timeout, send an interrupt to the HDB, with something like system"kill -2 ",string[PID]. I dont think this is full proof but an idea.